# How to establish subscription/publication communication within C++ code?

Tags: ros, talker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To establish communication (simple listen/talk) between two machines, I simply use

```
export ROS_HOSTNAME=ip1
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://ip2:11311
rosrun ...
```

However, if I want machine1 to communicate with machine2 without explicitly tell machine1, but rather I use a machine3 to tell machine1 the ip address of machine2 to make the connection. How should I achieve this through c++? Is there any code that's equivalent to the commands above?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/69409/how-to-establish-subscription/publication-communication-within-c++-code?/) by [Bholms](https://answers.ros.org/users/5097/bholms/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2013-07-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you have a third machine you want to use as a coordinator, why not run the roscore in machine3?

In your other machines you do:

```
export ROS_HOSTNAME=ip1
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://ip3:11311
```

---

Originally posted by [Victor Lopez](https://answers.ros.org/users/395/victor-lopez/) with karma: 651 on 2013-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bholms](https://answers.ros.org/users/5097/bholms/) on 2013-07-29**:
The problem is that if I have 100 machines, then I will have to do this for all of them... That's why I am thinking of doing it with C++.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-11-18**:
If you are setting up that many machines it is probably worth setting them up with proper hostnames so you don't need to reference their IPs.